# How to YAML save numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, save, yaml

Hi is there a way how to save numpy 2D array and then safely load it from a file? 
I have this array:

```
     matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=(self.row,self.col))
```

But I´m unable to save it

Comment: `np.save` don't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [24]: matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=(3,4))

In [25]: np.save('test', matrix)

In [26]: a = np.load('test.npy')

In [27]: matrix
Out[27]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [28]: a
Out[28]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 18):

The most obvious approach is to install the `pyyaml` module (which Google App Engine uses), and save the matrix as a list.

```
import numpy as np
import yaml
matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=(10,7))
with open('stack21658676.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(matrix.tolist(), f)

with open('stack21658676.yaml') as f:
    loaded = yaml.load(f)
loaded = np.array(loaded)
print loaded
```

Though I have to ask why you want YAML as opposed to the 'native' numpy save?

Comment: Currently loading yaml data needs extra argument. Use it like :  
yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)